# Building Breakout Game (python) but I can't get bricks to delete_?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a new coder and I am building a "Breakout" game in python and i got most of it to except getting the bricks to delete. *What is odd, is after the ball touches the bottom wall (out of bounds) and regenerates, the bricks are then able to be deleted by playing the game! Also, I need to stop the game after 3 chances. I'm stuck, with those 2 problems. Help please. Here is my code:

import tkinter
import time

```
# How big is the playing area?
CANVAS_WIDTH = 600  # Width of drawing canvas in pixels
CANVAS_HEIGHT = 800  # Height of drawing canvas in pixels

# Constants for the bricks
N_ROWS = 8  # How many rows of bricks are there?
N_COLS = 10  # How many columns of bricks are there?
SPACING = 5  # How much space is there between each brick?
BRICK_START_Y = 50  # The y coordinate of the top-most brick
BRICK_HEIGHT = 20  # How many pixels high is each brick
BRICK_WIDTH = (CANVAS_WIDTH - (N_COLS + 1) * SPACING) // N_COLS

# Constants for the ball and paddle
BALL_SIZE = 70
PADDLE_Y = CANVAS_HEIGHT - 40
PADDLE_WIDTH = 200


def main():
    canvas = make_canvas(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT, 'Brick Breaker')
    # Makes a ball
    ball = canvas.create_oval(300, 300, 350, 350, fill="red", outline="red")
    # Makes a paddle
    paddle = canvas.create_rectangle(299, PADDLE_Y, PADDLE_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT - 20, fill="black")
    # Change_X
    dx = 6
    # Change_Y
    dy = 6
    for row in range(N_ROWS):
        # Draws columns of brick
        for col in range(N_COLS):
            draw_brick(canvas, row, col)

    while True:
        # Mouse location and respond to movement
        mouse_x = canvas.winfo_pointerx()
        # Move Paddle to X location
        canvas.moveto(paddle, mouse_x, PADDLE_Y)
        # Ball movement
        canvas.move(ball, dx, dy)
        # If ball hits left of right wall, change X location
        if hit_left_wall(canvas, ball) or hit_right_wall(canvas, ball):
            dx *= -1
        # If ball hits top wall, then change Y location
        elif hit_top_wall(canvas, ball):
            dy *= -1
        elif hit_brick(canvas, ball, paddle):
            dy *= -1
        if hit_bottom(canvas, ball):
            canvas.delete(ball)
            ball = make_ball(canvas)

        # Recreates canvas
        canvas.update()
        # Pause time
        time.sleep(1 / 50.)

    canvas.mainloop()


# Finds coordinates of paddle
def hit_paddle(canvas, ball, paddle):
    paddle_coords = canvas.coords(paddle)
    x1 = paddle_coords[0]
    y1 = paddle_coords[1]
    x2 = paddle_coords[2]
    y2 = paddle_coords[3]
    # If any object begins to overlap with paddle, create a Hit
    result = canvas.find_overlapping(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    return len(result) > 1


def make_ball(canvas):
    return canvas.create_oval(300, 300, 350, 350, fill="red", outline="red")


def hit_brick(canvas, ball, paddle):
    ball_coord = canvas.coords(ball)
    x_1 = ball_coord[0]
    y_1 = ball_coord[1]
    x_2 = ball_coord[2]
    y_2 = ball_coord[3]
    results = canvas.find_overlapping(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2)
    for object in results:
        if object == paddle or object == ball:
            return len(results) > 1
        else:
            canvas.delete(object)


def moveto(canvas, oval, x, y):
    # Get current position
    x0, y0, x1, y1 = canvas.coords(oval)
    # Sets new position
    canvas.move(oval, x - x0, y - y0)


def hit_bottom(canvas, ball):
    return get_bottom_y(canvas, ball) >= CANVAS_HEIGHT


def hit_left_wall(canvas, ball):
    return get_left_x(canvas, ball) <= 0


def hit_right_wall(canvas, ball):
    return get_right_x(canvas, ball) >= CANVAS_WIDTH


def hit_top_wall(canvas, ball):
    return get_top_y(canvas, ball) <= 0


def draw_brick(canvas, row, col):
    x = col * (BRICK_WIDTH + SPACING)
    y = row * (BRICK_HEIGHT + SPACING)
    color = "blue"
    canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x + BRICK_WIDTH, y + BRICK_HEIGHT, fill=color, outline=color)


def get_bottom_y(canvas, ball):
    return canvas.coords(ball)[3]


def get_top_y(canvas, ball):
    """
    This friendly method returns the y coordinate of the top of an object.
    Recall that canvas.coords(object) returns a list of the object
    bounding box: [x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2]. The element at index 1 is the top-y
    """
    return canvas.coords(ball)[1]


def get_left_x(canvas, ball):
    """
    This friendly method returns the x coordinate of the left of an object.
    Recall that canvas.coords(object) returns a list of the object
    bounding box: [x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2]. The element at index 0 is the left-x
    """
    return canvas.coords(ball)[0]


def get_right_x(canvas, ball):
    """
    This friendly method returns the x coordinate of the right of an object.
    Recall that canvas.coords(object) returns a list of the object
    bounding box: [x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2]. The element at index 2 is the right-x
    """
    return canvas.coords(ball)[2]


def make_canvas(width, height, title):
    """
    Creates and returns a drawing canvas
    of the given int size with a blue border,
    ready for drawing.
    """
    top = tkinter.Tk()
    top.minsize(width=width, height=height)
    top.title(title)
    canvas = tkinter.Canvas(top, width=width + 1, height=height + 1)
    canvas.pack()
    return canvas


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is due to the if statement in the for loop inside `hit_brick()`:

```
def hit_brick(canvas, ball, paddle):
    ball_coord = canvas.coords(ball)
    x_1 = ball_coord[0]
    y_1 = ball_coord[1]
    x_2 = ball_coord[2]
    y_2 = ball_coord[3]
    results = canvas.find_overlapping(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2)
    for object in results:
        if object == paddle or object == ball: # <-- problem here
            return len(results) > 1
        else:
            canvas.delete(object)
```

As the values of `ball` and `paddle` are 1 and 2 (as they are the first two canvas items created) and so `results` is something like `(1, N)` when the ball hit one of the bricks.
So the if statement returns true for the first checking and then the function exits by the `return` statement.

Now let the ball hits the bottom and it will be recreated with id greater than existing canvas items.  The `results` will be something like `(N, ball)` when the ball hits one of the bricks.
This time the if statement will return false and the brick is deleted.

So `hit_brick()` should be modified as below:

```
def hit_brick(canvas, ball, paddle):
    ball_coord = canvas.coords(ball)
    results = canvas.find_overlapping(*ball_coord)
    for object in results:
        if object not in (paddle, ball):
            canvas.delete(object)
    return len(results) > 1
```

For the second problem, you need to declare a variable, for example `lives = 3`, before the while loop and decrease it by one if the ball hits the bottom.
The while loop should be terminated if `lives == 0`:

```
def main():
    ...
    lives = 3
    while lives > 0:
        ...
        if hit_bottom(canvas.ball):
            ...
            lives -= 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much ACW!  One more question, i tried adding the "lives" loop at the beginning of my code and then at the backend and at both times, the code doesn't execute.  There isn't any errors, it just wont't run at all, stays in a state of thinking.  Any thought? thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you said?